# Slicer not working with SSAS measure group security

Tags: excel, security, ssas, slicers

I have created a SSAS role but members of this role are unable to insert an excel slicer. Normal pivot table behaviour is permitted - can select permitted measure groups. There are no dimension restrictions in place. I get "A pivotTable, cube function or sliver using connection XXXX has failed to refresh. Continue to refresh all?". Even after refresh I am unable to insert a slicer or select from an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried out slicers and can't see them doing anything particularly weird to the query Excel sends to SSAS - like creating a cube or set.  (You can see the MDX Excel is using by installing [OLAP Pivottable Extensions](https://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/)).

When I select dimension members in the slicer, the MDX changes from a

```
SELECT
....
FROM Cube
```

to a

```
SELECT
....
FROM
   (SELECT .... FROM Cube)
```

where the inner SELECT includes the slicer tuple in the WHERE.

Maybe post some more detail about what this role **isn't** permitted to do?  (probably the reason you created it).